# "View" with article shown according to detection/selection language

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I would like to create a View (using the View module) to show my translated article separately according to the url path. Doing so, going to www.mysite.com/fr/blog should only show my article with the term "story" in french and going to www.mysite.com/en/blog should only show my article with the same term "story" in english.

- I added an Entity translation relationship
- I added an entity translation "language" set as "current user's language"

But none of my article are displayed on the views whatever the language path I use.

Here is my Views configuration:

[image: Entity translation filter]

[image: Views configuration]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a contextual filter based on the 1st argument (the language selection) and provide a default value if need be.

Answer (score 0):

When 'FR' detected on Url default language of website will be changed So you have to Set it to  `Default Site Language`

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I tried and it does not fix the problem.

Comment: I tried both settings individually, then together:
- putting language setting as "default site setting"  in OTHER section didn't work
- putting "Default site language" in entity translation FILTER didn't work
- putting language setting as "default site setting" + filter didn't work neither.

Comment: @Benjamin you're welcome, So the problem is another place, I did similar jobs on several sites and they worked correctly. what is you  language detection type in language settings?

Comment: In « User interface text language detection », I enabled the URL detection method and configure it to « path prefix ». Then for the order, I have Default and User enabled in second and third position. Session and Browser are disabled. In « Content language detection », the settings are exactly the same, except that there is one more choice: « Interface », that is also «disabled ». Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a contextual filter and set to use a url position if not provided. Use the 1st argument (the language selection) and provide a default value if need be.

EDIT:

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm not sure exactly what you are telling me here? When I write things in the "contextual filter", it adds things at the very end of the url. My url should be fr/blog and not blog/fr. Am I missing something?

Comment: see the edit to my post please.

Comment: Tank you @tenken, I tried the same config and am still having the same issue, none of my article shows up (not in english nor french).